# Distinguishing Bad Leverage Points from Vertical Outliers

Tags: regression, least-squares, robust

Going through Regression class notes (written mostly following Kutner`s book, I believe), there was a brief display of how, in some cases, robust residual plots (such as standardized LTS residuals), do a better job pinpointing outliers.

[image]

However, as a drawback, it claims that this kind of residual plot **can`t distinguish bad leverage points from vertical outliers**.

[image]

By what this image shows, I can`t figure out why this distinction is relevant, considering both types of points seem bad enough for your regular Least Squares model.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you create a data set with the three types of outlier and then fit a regression model to the data with all three outliers removed. Now, look at the same model fit to the data set with just one of the types added back in, and then repeat this process two more times. What you should see is that adding the vertical outlier will have relatively little effect on the estimated slope but will increase the standard error, adding the "good outlier" will have relatively little effect on the estimated slope but will decrease the standard error (and not in a good way), and adding the bad outlier will especially affect the estimated slope (see below with the three outliers at the end of the data).

```
mydata <- data.frame(matrix(c(1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,5,5,6,6,6,6,7,7,4,20,20,20,20,4),ncol=2,byrow=TRUE))
names(mydata) <- c("x","y")
set.seed(1234)
mydata <- mydata+rnorm(40,0,0.1)
mydata
##             x         y
## 1   0.8792934  1.013409
## 2   2.0277429  1.950931
## 3   2.1084441  1.955945
## 4   2.7654302  3.045959
## 5   3.0429125  2.930628
## 6   3.0506056  2.855180
## 7   3.9425260  4.057476
## 8   3.9453368  3.897634
## 9   3.9435548  3.998486
## 10  3.9109962  3.906405
## 11  3.9522807  4.110230
## 12  4.9001614  4.952441
## 13  4.9223746  4.929056
## 14  5.0064459  4.949874
## 15  6.0959494  5.837091
## 16  5.9889715  5.883238
## 17  6.9488990  6.781996
## 18  3.9088805 19.865901
## 19 19.9162828 19.970571
## 20 20.2415835  3.953410
summary(lm(y ~ x, data = mydata[-c(18,19,20),]))
## 
## Call:
## lm(formula = y ~ x, data = mydata[-c(18, 19, 20), ])
## 
## Residuals:
##       Min        1Q    Median        3Q       Max 
## -0.203052 -0.117649 -0.000694  0.076298  0.263643 
## 
## Coefficients:
##             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
## (Intercept)  0.10668    0.09183   1.162    0.264    
## x            0.96753    0.02158  44.828   <2e-16 ***
## ---
## Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1
## 
## Residual standard error: 0.137 on 15 degrees of freedom
## Multiple R-squared:  0.9926, Adjusted R-squared:  0.9921 
## F-statistic:  2010 on 1 and 15 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
summary(lm(y ~ x, data = mydata[-c(19,20),]))
## 
## Call:
## lm(formula = y ~ x, data = mydata[-c(19, 20), ])
## 
## Residuals:
##     Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
## -1.1184 -0.9854 -0.8684 -0.7738 15.0885 
## 
## Coefficients:
##             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
## (Intercept)   1.0800     2.5927   0.417    0.683
## x             0.9459     0.6120   1.546    0.142
## 
## Residual standard error: 3.884 on 16 degrees of freedom
## Multiple R-squared:  0.1299, Adjusted R-squared:  0.07552 
## F-statistic: 2.389 on 1 and 16 DF,  p-value: 0.1418
summary(lm(y ~ x, data = mydata[-c(18,20),]))
## 
## Call:
## lm(formula = y ~ x, data = mydata[-c(18, 20), ])
## 
## Residuals:
##       Min        1Q    Median        3Q       Max 
## -0.240295 -0.093376 -0.008793  0.078497  0.297234 
## 
## Coefficients:
##              Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
## (Intercept) -0.015162   0.053578  -0.283    0.781    
## x            0.999442   0.008565 116.693   <2e-16 ***
## ---
## Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1
## 
## Residual standard error: 0.1435 on 16 degrees of freedom
## Multiple R-squared:  0.9988, Adjusted R-squared:  0.9988 
## F-statistic: 1.362e+04 on 1 and 16 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
summary(lm(y ~ x, data = mydata[-c(18,19),]))
## 
## Call:
## lm(formula = y ~ x, data = mydata[-c(18, 19), ])
## 
## Residuals:
##     Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
## -2.3942 -0.8256  0.1345  0.9843  2.5573 
## 
## Coefficients:
##             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
## (Intercept)   3.2893     0.5297   6.209 1.25e-05 ***
## x             0.1346     0.0839   1.604    0.128    
## ---
## Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1
## 
## Residual standard error: 1.43 on 16 degrees of freedom
## Multiple R-squared:  0.1386, Adjusted R-squared:  0.08476 
## F-statistic: 2.574 on 1 and 16 DF,  p-value: 0.1282
```

As you note, they all cause problems, but the problems are different enough to make it worthwhile distinguishing between the types.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to help! I get it. Just would like to ask one thing: what exactly does this mean - "adding the "good outlier" will have relatively little effect on the estimated slope but will decrease the standard error (and not in a good way)"?

Comment: The x coefficient with all outliers omitted was 0.968 and had a standard error of 0.022. Adding in the "good leverage" point didn't bias the coefficient, with the coefficient becoming 0.999 but the standard error has now decreased to 0.009. The addition of this single point has made the null hypothesis less tenable in a disproportionate way. Also, note that whether an outlier is a "good" or a "bad" leverage point depends on what we were expecting: for an n-shaped association (with, say, a quadratic term to accommodate this), the "good" and "bad" leverage points could swap labels, for example.

Answer (score 1):

Your first plot uses a straight horizontal line through residuals to determine upper and lower bands of +/- 2.5 for outlier determination, and most of the data seems well modeled by the horizontal straight line. If the second plot also uses a straight line for outlier determination, but not a *horizontal* straight line as that does *not* appear to be a good model for most of the data, the result is as follows. Here I fit a straight line to all data, and added the same +/- 2.5 upper and lower bands for that fitted line.

[image: plot]

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to help! I get it. Just would like to ask one thing: what exactly does this mean - "adding the "good outlier" will have relatively little effect on the estimated slope but will decrease the standard error (**and not in a good way**)"?

Comment: That was written in the answer of @user215517 and not me, you should ask in the comment section of their answer. I personally do not understand what they wrote.

Comment: I meant to do that, it was here by mistake. Thanks.